# Some jquery plugins not working with new version of jquery library

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question about jQuery Plugins . I am using a checkbox styling plugin ,plugin using the jQuery lib version 1.4.2 and it works perfectly. But when I upgraded to jquery 1.7.1 ,my bad,its  not working, also no error in console.

Above issue faced so many times then I'd resolved with using the same jquery file along with plugin. But now I've a lot more effects in my web page and they are using latest versions of jquery, perhaps I can't revert back it to old

I am a newbie at jquery ,if this is the case it will be too difficult to debug what's happening. Any good  solutions for this ,in future I should have to  use jQuery? What are all the upgradation rules ?.

Comment: not logical there are no errors.. what browser console did you use to verify?

Comment: Yes there are no errors ,that  is the problem ,I am looking to blank, but its not stay selected if my check box selected

Comment: please supply a link to the specific plugin that's no longer working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, the most significant change from 1.4 to 1.7 that might cause code to break was the introduction in jQuery 1.6 of `.prop()` to replace some (mis)uses of `.attr()`.

Take a look at all calls to `.attr()` and see if they should be replaced with `.prop()`.

For guidance on which should be used, see http://appendto.com/blog/2011/05/jquery-161-release-executive-brief

Comment: Where I can see this update logs ,any jQuery website for this?

Comment: there are release notes, usually found via the jQuery blog when they announce new versions - http://blog.jquery.com/2012/03/09/jquery-1-7-2-rc1-released/

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same with jQuery Plugins (especially jQuery Tools) which required an older version of jQuery to run properly.

I'm sorry, but I would suggest ditching plugins that require an old version of something and do a few Google searches for some of the effects you're going for. The newer jQuery versions have newer and added effects themselves and the jQuery UI plugin also adds a bunch of new effects and transitions you might be interested in.

If jQuery Tools or anything similar using an older version of jQuery exists, there probably is a better, more new version made by somebody else somewhere on the Internet.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

> I am a newbie at jquery ,if this is the case it will be too difficult to debug what's happening. Any good solutions for this ,in future I should have to use jQuery? What are all the upgradation rules ?.

For this part, you can go for the trial and error procedure, just put the jQuery sources and make sure you do some regression testing, this will ensure you that all plugins work, and only after that go to dev/production with the new jQuery version.

As for new effects. Any new effect is basically a sum of previously introduced effects, so basically you have everything there, maybe it might be worth porting some plugins to newer jQuery version once you get the hang of it, or why not try to implement those plugins by yourself.

EDIT:

on the jquery website you can check the API and it will show for each API method signature in what version it was introduced.